# Core Plot - Customize x-axis Labels

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-graphics, core-plot

I want to draw graph using Core Plot Library. I try to customize the x-axis Labels such as shown in attached Image. [image: Graph Image]

this graph have two label on x-axis at one tick location. and title of axis at origin. Can i draw this type of graph using Core Plot or not ? If yes, how i can do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. However you will have to use the latest coreplot code from the repository. AFAIK the attributed label formatter support no available yet in the latest official release. With that formatter you can give your labels the form you want (and use only one label with a line break, instead 2).